# Separating then stacking 3D mat files

Tags: matlab, while-loop

So I have a large amount of mostly 2D mat files that I need to stack, however some of the files were saved in 3d, i.e. they are 1024*1024*2. I'm struggling to write a while loop that will separate the 3d files and stack them while also stacking the normal 2d files.

Comment: is mat file the one used in MATLAB?

Comment: yes the files are in matrix form 1024*1024*1 is what they should be but some are 1024*1024*2

Answer (score 0):

function [ndims(matrix)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndims.html) give you the dimension of a matrix so, for the 3 dimensional ones you can do:

```
if ndims(A)==3
   A=[A(:,:,1);A(:,:,2)] % stack the 2 layers of matrix A vertically
end
```